# How can I implement status bar for state transition in xaf blazor .net 6 application

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, devexpress, xaf

[image]

I need a status bar like this. I have no idea how to do this. Is any reference available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a base to Work on you could use a Component like this:

```
<div class="status-bar">
    <div class="bar filled" style="width: @GetFilledPercentage()%"></div>
    <div class="bar empty" style="width: @GetEmptyPercentage()%"></div>
    <div class="status-bar-checkpoints">
        @foreach (var checkpoint in Checkpoints) {
            <div class="checkpoint">
                <div class="checkpoint-cirlce @GetCirlceClass(checkpoint)">
                </div>
                <p class="checkpoint-text">
                    @checkpoint.Name
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ICollection<Checkpoint> Checkpoints { get; set; } = new List<Checkpoint>();

    private string GetCirlceClass(Checkpoint checkpoint) {
        return checkpoint.Status switch {
            CheckpointStatus.Checked => "checked",
            CheckpointStatus.Current => "current",
            CheckpointStatus.Unchecked => "unchecked",
            _ => ""
        };
    }

    private int GetFilledPercentage() {
        return Checkpoints.Count(x => x.Status == CheckpointStatus.Checked ) * 100 / (Checkpoints.Count - 1);
    }
    private int GetEmptyPercentage() {
        return 100 - GetFilledPercentage();
    }
}
```

This creates the base for all html elements that you need including the text. To style it in a way that it shows a status bar. The css I created looks like that:

```css
.status-bar{
    position: relative;
}

.status-bar-checkpoints {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.checkpoint {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.checkpoint-cirlce {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px #CCC solid;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: white;
}

    .checkpoint-cirlce.current {
        border: 5px #c43535 solid;
    }

    .checkpoint-cirlce.checked {
        background: #c43535;
        border: 5px #c43535 solid;
    }

.bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
    .bar.filled {
        background: #c43535;
        padding-left: 10px;
        left: 10px;
    }
    .bar.empty {
        background: #CCC;
        right: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

To make the status bar reusable in different locations I use a class saves the data of the checkpoints (Name and status). That is used in the component to create the status bar. I use a record class for that.

```cs
public record Checkpoint(string Name, CheckpointStatus Status);

public enum CheckpointStatus {
    Unchecked,
    Current,
    Checked
}
```

The enum represents the Status of the Checkpoint.

To use the Component you have to create a `ICollection<Checkpoint>` (for example `Array` or `List`) and hand it to the Component, a simple example to use the component looks like that:

```
<StatusBar Checkpoints="_checkpoints"/>

@code{
    private Checkpoint[] _checkpoints = new Checkpoint[] {
        new Checkpoint("Open", CheckpointStatus.Checked),
        new Checkpoint("Qualified", CheckpointStatus.Checked),
        new Checkpoint("Develop", CheckpointStatus.Current),
        new Checkpoint("Propose", CheckpointStatus.Unchecked),
        new Checkpoint("Closed", CheckpointStatus.Unchecked),
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You've explained in detail :)

Comment: @Shammu did you manage to do it, can you help me